# How to input '-' using rename()

Tags: r, variables, select, dplyr, rename

There are some errors in using FUMA, so I tried to change a variable name by using rename().
But it takes error with this quote:

```
#download.file("ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gwas/summary_statistics/JansenIE_30617256_GCST007320/AD_sumstats_Jansenetal_2019sept.txt.gz", "AD_sumstats_Jansenetal_2019sept.txt.gz")

AD_GCST007320 <- read.delim("AD_sumstats_Jansenetal_2019sept.txt.gz", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

AD_GCST007320 <- select(AD_GCST007320, CHR, BP, A1, A2, SNP, Z, P, Nsum, EAF, BETA, SE)

rename(AD_GCST007320, p-value = P)
```

> ## Error: unexpected '=' in "rename(AD_GCST007320, p-value ="

I had checked that error occurs using - in p-value. So I want to know how to put - using rename().

Comment: Welcome to SO; Presume this is using the `dplyr` package?

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you can use the name like that with

```
rename(AD_GCST007320, `p-value` = P)
```

but I highly discourage you from doing so because every time you would need to refer to that column using backticks. As Magnus wrote use e.g. `_` or `.`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `-` is a special character (minus). Replace it with `_` or `.` and you should be fine.

See:
https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-successfully-follow-naming-conventions-in-r/